# Transition between image to text within div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to get a transition between an image and text. A screenshot of my site is [here](http://s7.postimg.org/qwh7of8xn/imageblock.png) which shows the image of a film. On hover i want the description of the film, which will be `$row['description']` to transition in and then on click be taken to the relevant page.

```
  <div class="row">
<?php 
    $numrow = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6'>";
    echo "<a href='#' class='thumbnail'>";
    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='http://url/assets/posters/".$row['id']."_medium.jpg'>";
    echo "</a></div>";
} ?>
</div>
```

Im not really sure where to start so appologies for the the lack of information. All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can perform a CSS overlay technique (google can help you) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, consider posting your HTML for better answers. This would serve you as a start. You need to have both the image and the text in the same `<div>` with an `absolute` position. And you can apply the hover styles like this, just using CSS alone:

```css
.item {position: relative; border: 1px solid #999; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; width: 250px; height: 330px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;}
.item img,
.item p {position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border-radius: 5px; text-align: center; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.65); margin: 0; z-index: 1; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s; transition: all 0.5s;}
.item p {padding: 5px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;}
.item:hover p {opacity: 1;}
.item:hover img {opacity: 0.25;}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/240/320/nature/1/" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum a eligendi sunt necessitatibus? Consequuntur, animi neque architecto.</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/240/320/cats/1/" alt="" />
  <p>Nihil fugiat fuga sequi unde eum sunt alias doloribus obcaecati aut nostrum! Rerum, sint repellat reprehenderit dolorum quis inventore!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. This solution has worked for me! Thank you for the quick reply!